# Kubernetes: Disaster recovery

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, high-availability, disaster-recovery

I am currently working on Kube deployment, unfortunatelly we have only 2 locations and the requirements are that we need to tolerate one location failure. It is not required that it must be automatic or zero downtime (so it is not expected to be HA, we just want disaster recovery).

I am completely aware that 2 masters cluster has lower availability than 1 master cluster. But the idea is that with two masters, when one location fails (or is taken down), admin will spin up another new master in the other location, ensuring majority.

Expected advantage over single master: The state of the cluster should survive location failure (we have also Postgres and other stateful components in Kube and we want Postgres to reconfigure slave to master, if node with master is taken down).

Is this approach sane? Or is there some other way how to deploy Kube in 2 locations?

Comment: Create a federation of two clusters but not schedule pods in one cluster (kubectl uncordon)

Comment: unfortunatelly I need to have there at least DB slaves...sot his would have to be selective somehow